# Swift3: HTTP POST request with parameters divided by "/"

Tags: php, ios, swift, swift3, httprequest

This is the acceptable POST request that server(using codeigniter) accepts.

As it is shown, it doesn't take keys, but only values.

The first value starts with "/", and "/" is used between values.

```
http://example.com/index.php/api/signup/value01/value02/value03
```

I have this code, written in Swift3.

```
let serverUrl = "http://example.com/index.php/api/signup"
let parameterString = "/value01/value02/value03"

let url: URL = URL(string: serverUrl)!
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
request.httpBody = parameterString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in 

}) task.resume()
```

It gets an error, and the server responds that it didn't receive any parameter.

But, if I copy paste the below code to Browser, it works perfect.

```
http://example.com/index.php/api/signup/value01/value02/value03
```

The swift3 code worked for another server, which accepted POST requests written this way.

```
http://example.com/api?key=value&key=value
```

Comment: Then just make all the params combine into the url for it to become the one u have? this doesnt seems like the normal post body so probably it wont do anything

Comment: You should use URLRequest declaring it as variable instead of using NSMutableRequest

Comment: You should be appending `parameterString` to `serverUrl` instead of setting it as a HTTP body. When you set it as HTTP body, even the API must be programmed to read from the body, which is not in this case. Its looking for data in the URL not in the body.

Comment: @GoodSp33d I combined all the params into one url and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @LeoDabus I used URLRequest with other suggestions, and it does its job. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Tj3n @Leo Dabus @GoodSp33d !

I was able to solve the problem, using your suggestions.

The server php also used "URL-encode RFC 1738 (e.g. "%E6%84%9B" for "愛")" for certain string values.

So, I added

```
let newString = oldString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
```

to encode some string values and the problem solved.

So, this is the solution in a simplified version.

```
let serverUrl = "http://example.com/index.php/api/signup/value01/value02/value03"

let url: URL = URL(string: serverUrl)!
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in 

}) task.resume()
```

This is the real POST request url that my code sent.

```
http://example.com/index.php/api/signup/1282283772/none/0204291/%E6%84%9B/0/70/null
```